# Making data wide where row names are not identical

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to get a model results table into wide format. Since names are not the same on outcomes (dv variables), NA's show up in the table and I can't find a way to have one row per variable.

I need one row per variable/dv. Model 1 and 3 share all variables other than one.

Data:

```
table <- data.frame(variable=c("intercept", "a", "b", "intercept", "c", "intercept", "a", "e", "intercept", "c"), 
                    b=c(1.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.9, 1.3, 2, .23, .4, .7), 
                    p=(abs(rnorm(10, 0, .3))),
                    model=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4),
                    dv=c(rep("dv1", 5), rep("dv2", 5)))

> table
            variable    b          p model  dv
        1  intercept 1.20 0.03320481     1 dv1
        2          a 0.10 0.16675234     1 dv1
        3          b 0.40 0.53607394     1 dv1
        4  intercept 0.30 0.14935514     2 dv1
        5          c 0.90 0.58998515     2 dv1
        6  intercept 1.30 0.21040677     3 dv2
        7          a 2.00 0.14183742     3 dv2
        8          e 0.23 0.32034711     3 dv2
        9  intercept 0.40 0.06539247     4 dv2
        10         c 0.70 0.30780133     4 dv2
```

Code:

```
table %>% 
  gather(key, value, b, p) %>% unite("stat_var", dv, key, sep=".") %>%
  spread(stat_var, value) %>%
  arrange(model, desc(variable))
```

Output:

```
    variable model dv1.b      dv1.p dv2.b      dv2.p
1  intercept     1   1.2 0.21866737    NA         NA
2          b     1   0.4 0.50600799    NA         NA
3          a     1   0.1 0.18751178    NA         NA
4  intercept     2   0.3 0.25133611    NA         NA
5          c     2   0.9 0.04601194    NA         NA
6  intercept     3    NA         NA  1.30 0.34144108
7          e     3    NA         NA  0.23 0.12793927
8          a     3    NA         NA  2.00 0.37614448
9  intercept     4    NA         NA  0.40 0.08852144
10         c     4    NA         NA  0.70 0.26853770
```

Looking for:

[image]

Comment: Please do not use images to share results. Also, it seems that your output is wrong: the first row implies a `dv2` value with `model==1` and `variable ==intercept` which is never found in your sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will ignore the reason (I see there's no valid reason) to consider some type of "equivalence" between models (handled it with mutate()). But related only with the table manipulation, I have this basic option to get your desired output:

You can use pivot_wider_spec() to set the names b and p like suffixs.

```
require(tidyverse)

table %>% 
  mutate(model = case_when(model == 3 ~ 1,
                           model == 4 ~ 2,
                           TRUE ~ model)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = dv, values_from = c("b", "p")) %>% 
  select(variable,
         model,
         ends_with("dv1"),
         ends_with("dv2"))

# A tibble: 6 x 6
# variable  model b_dv1  p_dv1 b_dv2   p_dv2
# <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#   1 intercept     1   1.2  0.318  1.3   0.200 
# 2 a             1   0.1  0.120  2     0.419 
# 3 b             1   0.4  0.309 NA    NA     
# 4 intercept     2   0.3  0.350  0.4   0.0148
# 5 c             2   0.9  0.185  0.7   0.530 
# 6 e             1  NA   NA      0.23  0.174
```

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in my comment, it seems that your expected output is wrong.

However, you can reproduce it by tweaking the `model` variable:

```r
table %>% 
  select(model, everything()) %>% 
  mutate(model=ifelse(model>2, model-2, model)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(b, p)) %>% 
  unite("name", c("dv", "name")) %>% 
  pivot_wider()
# # A tibble: 6 x 6
#   model variable  dv1_b   dv1_p dv2_b  dv2_p
#   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     1 intercept   1.2  0.193   1.3   0.160
# 2     1 a           0.1  0.650   2     0.476
# 3     1 b           0.4  0.190  NA    NA    
# 4     2 intercept   0.3  0.0435  0.4   0.145
# 5     2 c           0.9  0.372   0.7   0.243
# 6     1 e          NA   NA       0.23  0.297
```

Of note, `gather()` and `spread()` are deprecated in favor of pivoting functions which offer very nice improvements (although not used here).